# Promote server to a domain controller to join domain across internet

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, dns

I have been facing this issue well over couple of weeks now. I can use some guidance and help.

Current Setup:

1. Aws ec2 instance (windows 2012 r2 server) hosting "abcd.com" domain. It is also a DNS server. Also, Elastic public IP has been attached.
2. Server I am promoting is in different VPC (let's say my own personal computer). Also running windows server 2012 r2. Configured DNS settings to point to Elastic public IP of aws instance.
3. I am able to perform "nslookup abcd.com" which returns private ip of the aws instance. Unable to perform ping though (since it resolves to private ip).
4. I tried configuring the dns entry on aws instance so it maps to elastic public ip. after that i was able to ping "abcd.com". But this seemed dirty to me.

Overall, I am not able to promote my pc to the domain controller which is on aws instance. If I put domain controller and server being promoted in same network, it works like a charm (don't even need a public IP in that case). But keeping it in separate networks things aren't working for me. Your inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want to use public IP address, then try VPC peering.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This might fit Server Fault, but do check their help section first and search for suitable existing questions which might help you

Comment: @DusanBajic: I am ok to use public ip, can i still achieve this setup without using VPC peering?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes surely i'll post there as well. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds a lot like firewall issues to me. I would not recommend to build an Active Directory network with public facing IP addresses but if you want to do so, try to deactivate all firewalls between your Domain Controller and your computer (I would do this only for testing purposes and never in an productive environment)

Comment: @TobyU I did disable the firewall on aws instance, but I can try to disable the promoting server firewall as well. Just to see if this works (testing only)